# 値をpost送信した際の送信先でのjavascriptを使用した取得、設定方法

Tags: javascript, php, html, form

大変お世話になっております。

あるサイト①から他のサイト②を開く際に①の値をget送信し、その開いたサイト②にて、urlから値を取得し、更に他のサイト③にその値を送信するために、その値を②にて代入する以下の様な設定が機能しております。

これをget送信でなく、method="post"の様にpost送信にした場合、サイト②ではどのように取得し、値を代入すれば宜しいかご教授頂けませんでしょうか。

つまり、以下のサイト①でmethod="post"を使用した場合のサイト②内でのjavascriptの記述方法をご教授頂けませんでしょうか。

```
サイト①
<form name="reserve" method="get" action="http://xxxx.com/send.html">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{$product.id}" />
<input type="submit" value="送信する" class="sendButton">
</form>


サイト②
http://xxxx.com/send.html?id=7

<script type="text/javascript"> 
const url = new URL(location.href);
const id = url.searchParams.get("id");
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
document.getElementById('id').value = id;
  });
</script>

<form id="Form" method="post" action="xxxxxxx">
<input name="id" id="id" type="hidden" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="送信する" class="sendButton">
</form>
```

追記：

```
サイト①
php:
<?php
    $post_json_data = json_encode($_POST);
?>


<form name="reserve" method="post" action="http://xxxx.com/send.html">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{$product.id}" />
<input type="hidden" name="cusotmer_id" value="{$smarty.get.cusotmer_id}" />
<input type="submit" value="送信する" class="sendButton">
</form>


サイト②
http://xxxx.com/send.html

<script type="text/javascript"> 
const post_data = <?php echo $post_json_data; ?>;
</script>

＊＊＊
<h1><input type="text" disabled name="cusotmer_id" id="cusotmer_id" value=""></h1>

<form id="Form" method="post" action="xxxxxxx">
<input name="id" id="id" type="hidden" value="" />
<input name="customer_id" id="customer_id" type="hidden" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="送信する" class="sendButton">
</form>
```

頂きました記述をもとに、json_encode、およびもう一方の個々に取得する方法の両者を試しておりますが、どうしても両者とも値を取得、そして設定できません。

実際は、値が複数存在しますので、json_encodeで試した記述を追記に補足しました。サイト②のjavascriptで取得した値であるpost_dataはどのようにhtml上でそれぞれのvalueに設定されるのでしょうか。試しにサイト②の＊＊＊でcusotmer_idを表示させてみると[object HTMLCollection] と表示されます。

Answer (score 1):

PHPからHTML側のJavascriptにサーバ側のデータを渡す方法はいくつかありますが、
一般的には[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.json-encode.php)を利用することが多いと思います。

```
<?php
    $post_json_data = json_encode($_POST);
?><html>
  <head>
  <head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        const post_data = <?php echo $post_json_data; ?>;
    </script>
  <body>
<html>
```

ただ今回の場合のように特定の値一つだけで、値の無害化を**確実にもれなく十分に**実行できるような場合は直接渡してしまっても良いとは思います。

```
<?php
    //例として必ずidにはint型しか入らないという前提の弱い無害化
    $id = (int)$_POST["id"];
?><html>
  <head>
  <head>
  <body>
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
        const id = <?php echo $id;?>;
    </script>
  <body>
<html>
```

以下はWebのサーバとクライアントの基礎知識です。
もしご存知の場合は、飛ばして頂いてOKです。

クライアントはサーバにリクエストします。
サーバはリクエストに対してレスポンスを返します。

PHPはサーバサイドの言語、HTML側のJavascriptはクライアントサイドの言語です。
そしてPOSTとはクライアントサイドからリクエストする方式の一つです

そのためイメージとしては
（HTML+Javascript）→（PHP）→（HTML+Javascript）→（PHP）→（HTML+Javascript）→…
とデータをクライアントに返す、データをサーバに送るを繰り返します。

Comment: keitaro_so様、ご教授頂きまして感謝致します。追記致しました。どこに問題があるかお教え願いませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

単純にpostで'data1=a1&data2=a2&data3=a3&data4=a4'を送り、サーバからの結果をjsonで受けるサンプルを書いて見ました。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log(xhr.response);
                var datas = xhr.response;
                console.log(' data1:'+datas.data1);
                console.log(' data2:'+datas.data2);
                console.log(' data3:'+datas.data3);
                console.log(' data4:'+datas.data4);

            } else {
                console.log("status = " + xhr.status);
            }
        }
    };

    var senddata = 'data1=a1&data2=a2&data3=a3&data4=a4';

    xhr.open("POST", 'index.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.responseType = "json";
    xhr.send(senddata);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.phpは**

```
<?php

$data1 = $_POST['data1'];
$data2 = $_POST['data2'];
$data3 = $_POST['data3'];
$data4 = $_POST['data4'];

$arr_data = array('data1'=>$data1,'data2'=>$data2,'data3'=>$data3,'data4'=>$data4);

$json_str = json_encode($arr_data);

echo $json_str;
```

Comment: yyz様、ご教授頂きまして本当に感謝いたします。頂いた記述をもとに、私のケースに合う様に様々な方法で試しておりますが、もう一方の記述も含め、どうしてもhtml側で値を取得できません。
具体的には頂いた記述をまずはどの様にform内のvalueに当てはめ、そして送信する様に設定すれば宜しいのでしょうか。
（私の上記の質問に合う様に設定すれば宜しいでしょうか）